# Monaco-editor with vscode extension webpack webview

Tags: javascript, webpack, vscode-extensions, monaco-editor, webpack-plugin

I am trying to implement monaco-editor into custom vscode extension and I've tried it in so many ways to import it, but I cannot figure it out (there are either random errors from monaco-editor files, problems with imports inside those files - err:access_denied, or even import * as monaco from "monaco-editor". Did someone maybe figure it out and be willing to help me out? I am using typescript project from vscode extension generator. Basically, what I try to do is for the chatgpt output code to style it the same way as monaco editor into my webview, however even a simple monaco editor with random code doesn't work. Here are some files to help.

webpack.config.js

```
//@ts-check

'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require("webpack");
// const dotenv = require('dotenv');
require('dotenv').config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, '.env') });
const MonacoWebpackPlugin = require('monaco-editor-webpack-plugin');

// this will update the process.env with environment variables in .env file
// dotenv.config( { path: path.resolve(__dirname, '.env') } );

//@ts-check
/** @typedef {import('webpack').Configuration} WebpackConfig **/

/** @type WebpackConfig */
const extensionConfig = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": JSON.stringify(process.env)
    }),
    // new MonacoWebpackPlugin({
    //   "publicPath": "/dist/"
    // })
  ],
  target: 'node', // VS Code extensions run in a Node.js-context  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/
    mode: 'development', // this leaves the source code as close as possible to the original (when packaging we set this to 'production')

  // entry: './src/extension.ts', // the entry point of this extension,  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/
  entry: {
    extension: './src/extension.ts',
    'editor.worker': 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.worker.js',
    'json.worker': 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/json/json.worker',
    'css.worker': 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/css/css.worker',
    'html.worker': 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/html/html.worker',
    'ts.worker': 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/typescript/ts.worker',
  },
  output: {
    // the bundle is stored in the 'dist' folder (check package.json),  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js',
  },
  externals: {
    vscode: 'commonjs vscode' // the vscode-module is created on-the-fly and must be excluded. Add other modules that cannot be webpack'ed,  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/
    // modules added here also need to be added in the .vscodeignore file
  },
  resolve: {
    // support reading TypeScript and JavaScript files,  -> https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.ttf$/,
        use: ['file-loader'],
      },
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  watchOptions: {
    ignored: /node_modules/,
  },
  infrastructureLogging: {
    level: "log", // enables logging required for problem matchers
  },
};
module.exports = extensionConfig;
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2017",
        "module": "esnext",
        "outDir": "out",
        "strict": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "baseUrl": "./node_modules",
        "types": ["node", "webpack-env"]
    },
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "declutter",
  "displayName": "declutter",
  "description": "An extension that declutters human brain",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.78.0"
  },
  "categories": [
    "Other"
  ],
  "activationEvents": [
    "onView:declutter.MainView"
  ],
  "main": "./dist/extension.js",
  "contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "declutter.askGPT",
        "title": "Ask GPT"
      },
      {
        "command": "declutter.history",
        "title": "History",
        "icon": "media/icons/history.png"
      }
    ],
    "menus": {
      "view/title": [
        {
          "when": "view == declutter.MainView",
          "command": "declutter.history",
          "group": "navigation"
        }
      ],
      "editor/context": [
        {
          "command": "declutter.askGPT",
          "when": "editorHasSelection",
          "group": "declutter"
        }
      ]
    },
    "viewsContainers": {
      "activitybar": [
        {
          "id": "declutter",
          "title": "Declutter",
          "icon": "media/icons/finall.svg"
        }
      ]
    },
    "views": {
      "declutter": [
        {
          "type": "webview",
          "id": "declutter.MainView",
          "name": "Chat"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "configuration": {
    "title": "Declutter",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "declutter.helloWorld": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "Declutter Hello World",
        "order": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "vscode:prepublish": "npm run package",
    "compile": "webpack --config ./webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "concurrently \"rollup -c -w\" \"webpack --watch --config ./webpack.config.js\"",
    "build": "node ../node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress",
    "package": "webpack --mode production --devtool hidden-source-map",
    "compile-tests": "tsc -p . --outDir out",
    "watch-tests": "tsc -p . -w --outDir out",
    "pretest": "npm run compile-tests && npm run compile && npm run lint",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts",
    "test": "node ./out/test/runTest.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/glob": "^8.1.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.10",
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^20.8.5",
    "@types/vscode": "^1.83.0",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.18.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.7.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.7.5",
    "@vscode/test-electron": "^2.3.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^8.0.1",
    "esbuild": "^0.19.8",
    "eslint": "^8.51.0",
    "glob": "^10.3.10",
    "mocha": "^10.2.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vscode/codicons": "^0.0.35",
    "concurrently": "^8.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "dt-python-parser": "^0.9.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "jquery-resizable-dom": "^0.35.0",
    "monaco-editor": "^0.44.0",
    "monaco-editor-webpack-plugin": "^7.1.0",
    "openai": "^4.12.1",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "util": "^0.12.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, but perhaps it can point you in the right direction.  I split the project up into two.  One project is the "server side" which is the TypeScript code which is not in the webview and "client side" which is the code in the webview.  The "client side" is a Vite React project which fully compiles down with "npm run build". It then is pulled from the output directory into the "server side" project to load in the webview.  Also there are tricks needed referenced in the Monico editor docs about Vite so that it doesn't eat the code. I'm trying to figure out the webworker part.

Comment: Ah, I just got the web workers working as well.  If you add the Vite import query "&inline" on the end of the import Vite will automatically convert the webworker code into a base64 string so that you don't have to fetch it into a blob first. import editorWorker from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.worker?worker&inline';

Comment: Thank you very much @Joshua, I will try this way. I am new to this, so just to clarify, you propose to restructure the project to be build without webpack like here [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-webview-ui-toolkit-samples/tree/main/frameworks/hello-world-react-vite)?

Comment: I suppose, but I would use Vite's project generator for react directly so that you don't start with a possibly out of date project. https://vitejs.dev/guide/